# Streaming web based controller games with Steam

Tags: steam, streaming, steam-in-home-streaming

I want to be able to stream web based games from my PC. I created a Chrome shortcut in Steam which loads the site I want in kiosk mode (fullscreen with no address bar or browser menus). I tried streaming it to my MacBook and it loaded up fine. I could see it and I thought “great”. However when I went to try and control it, my controller was not recognised. Only mouse/keyboard worked. This is despite the controller working fine when I load the site directly on my desktop or when streaming a native game through Steam.

So, my question is does anyone know how to get Steam streaming controllers to work in Chrome (or any other browser)? Do I need to do something to get the browser to recognise the Steam controller driver as a proper controller?

Comment: Is your controller connected to your dekstop pc or MacBook? If it's connected to MacBook, then what happens if you open the game on your MacBook using Chrome? Does Chrome/game recognise your controller?